# Query to select elements where starts with elements in another list

Tags: c#, linq, select, lambda, entity-framework-core

I have 3 related table :

DailyTimeSheet -> User -> OrganizationUnit

Now, I want to select some rows from DailyTimeSheet where User's OrganizationUnit starts with one of my CurrentOrganizationUnits List.

I wrote this query but has error:

```cs
var newquery = filteredDailyWorkTimeSheets
    .Where(e => e.UserFk.OrganizationUnits
        .Where(j => CurrentOrganizationUnits.Any(k => j.OrganizationUnitId.ToString().StartsWith(k.ToString())))
        .Any()
    );
```

Error Message :

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<UserOrganizationUnit>()
.Where(u0 => __ef_filter__p_9 || !(((ISoftDelete)u0).IsDeleted) && __ef_filter__p_10 || ((IMayHaveTenant)u0).TenantId == __ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_11)
.Where(u0 => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: User
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: Inner
    IsNullable: True
, "Id") != null && object.Equals(
    objA: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(EntityShaperExpression: 
        EntityType: User
        ValueBufferExpression: 
            ProjectionBindingExpression: Inner
        IsNullable: True
    , "Id"), 
    objB: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(u0, "UserId")))
.Where(u0 => __myOUnits_0
    .Any(k => k.ToString() == "" || u0.OrganizationUnitId.ToString() != null && k.ToString() != null && u0.OrganizationUnitId.ToString().StartsWith(k.ToString())))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: Try replacing Any by FirstOrDefault

Comment: Have you tried to use explicit client evaluation by adding a `.ToList()` on the end?

Comment: @viveknuna  ERROR : Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: @JHizzal Nope, Not working, same error

Comment: First get the ids from CurrentOrganizationUnits and put them in a local list. Then you can do the 'Any' on that list.

Comment: @Poiter    CurrentOrganizationUnits  is a local list in this code.

Comment: Sorry, did not see it correct...

Comment: You cannot use local collections with EF Core, with one exception `Contains`. This query is doable but needs dynamic Expression Tree creation.

Comment: I think that you may use SelectMany, this way may return all the results.